# What is the best way to sort an array of strings by the percentage in their strings in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, string-parsing

I have the array:

```
["John (50%)", "Michael (10%)", "Amy (20%)", "Susan (100%)"]
```

And I need to sort that array according with the major % to the least %.
I can use lodash if that's the case, but besides that I just need to use vanilla JS.

Any idea what can be the best approach?

The final result should be:

```
["Susan (100%)", "John (50%)", "Amy (20%)", "Michael (10%)"]
```

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment on this matter.

Answer (score 4):

You could get the numerical value and sort descending by the delta of the values.

```js
var array = ["John (50%)", "Michael (10%)", "Amy (20%)", "Susan (100%)"];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getValue(s) { return s.match(/\d+/) || 0; }
    return getValue(b) - getValue(a);
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = ["John (50%)", "Michael (10%)", "Amy (20%)", "Susan (100%)"];
array.sort((a, b) => (a.match(/\d+/) || 0) - (b.match(/\d+/) || 0));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
var data = ["John (50%)", "Michael (10%)", "Amy (20%)", "Susan (100%)"];
var res = data.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.match(/\d+/) -  a.match(/\d+/);
});
console.log(res);
```